# Android xml parsing using SAX parser attribute having multiple child with same name and different id's

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

How to parse this xml using sax parser and get the access value for some particular id.

```
<AccessGroup>
<Access ID="1">1</Access>
<Access ID="2">1</Access>
<Access ID="3">0</Access>
<Access ID="4">0</Access>
<Access ID="5">1</Access>
<Access ID="6">0</Access>
<Access ID="7">1</Access>
<Access ID="8">1</Access>
<Access ID="9">1</Access>
</AccessGroup>
```

Comment: And what did you tried?

Comment: Element accessGroup = paylodElement.getChild("AccessGroup");
if(int i=0 ; i <= ((Object) accessGroup).getLenghh(); i++)               {
 Element access = paylodElement.getChild("Access");
}                                                                          but i want value of access only 3,7,9th element.                      i know its wrong, but m not getting it.

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing in that for loop: `String id = access.getAttribute("ID"); if (/*if the attribute id is one of the desired ones than use the value*/)`?

Comment: if(int i= 0; i <= ((Attributes) accessGroupElement).getLength(); i++){
  String id = accessElement.getAttribute("ID");
  if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
     String firstValue = accessElement.getAttribute("ID");
 }
  if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("7")){
     String secondValue = accessElement.getAttribute("ID");
 }
  if(id.equalsIgnoreCase("9")){
     Element thirdValue = accessElement.getAttribute("ID");
 }                                                                                   i am doing it like this but how to access the corresponding value for that particular id.

Comment: Please at least read the documentation, you have the `getNodeValue()` method.

Comment: getAttribute("ID"); and getNodeValue(); showing error for me          The method getAttribute(String) is undefined for the type Element